What status code should be returned from load balancer/reverse proxy when hostname does not match any rules?
Let's say we have an AWS application load balancer that has 2 rules based on host headers and a default rule for when the previous 2 rules' conditions aren't met.
What is the most appropriate HTTP status code to return for the default rule? Hitting the load balancer directly (or via a hostname not listed in the 2 non-default rules) won't return anything, so 404 seems like it could be appropriate. However, would a 5xx error (e.g. 500, 502 or 503) be more appropriate?

5xx errors indicate a problem with the underlying server, which isn't the case for a hostname mismatch. I think 404 is appropriate.

Though it isn't part of the HTTP spec, HTTP client error code 444 is often used for this situation.
You should just drop the connection with no response as this type of traffic is typically malicious. But since ALB requires you configure a response, a 404 or 401 might be more desirable as it is opaque to the client and so won't indicate to a crawler that there is a host header mismatch.

The most appropriate status code in this case would be "406". The official MDN document says: "This response is sent when the web server, after performing server-driven content negotiation, doesn't find any content that conforms to the criteria given by the user agent."
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406

Isn't 406 more to do with Accept[-*] headers though (specifically the request's proactive content negotiation headers)? Not sure it's applicable here since the rules are based on the Host header

Found a few similar questions where the answers suggest a 400 Bad Request may be applicable:

Http response code for invalid/missed host name
https://serverfault.com/questions/894426/http-status-code-to-signal-bad-or-missing-host-header

However, since the request is syntactically well-formed, and the host header exists and is valid (as in, it's not an invalid/malformed URI), a 404 feels more appropriate. This is also reflected by the fact that both IIS and Azure Application Gateway return 404 when the host header doesn't match any configured site or listener rules (see here).
